# How is the liquidity token.liq working

Tags: smart-contracts, liquidity

I'm asking for help because i don't really understand how the token.liq works and mostly what the functions needs.

For exemple I don't seem to be able to get the balance of an account.

In the input flield of the "BalanceOf" function I put an address (sender) and in the second (forward) input I think I should put a Contact address.
But i don't understand why. and what contract.

here is the link to the contract: http://www.liquidity-lang.org/edit/

if anyone is able to help that would be great.
Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Liquidity/Michelson, a program does not return a value. It returns the new storage and a list of new operations. So, the equivalent of a function returning a value is actually a program that takes a contract and transfers to this contract, with the value as argument. The contract will do whatever it is supposed to do with the balance, in the case of token. It’s called continuation passing style.